# How to write rails active record call back class after_create_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I want to use classes callback to reuse callback for difference model, I write `after_create_commit` method but when I use it in model then the model is saved it yields

```
undefined method `after_commit`
```

For example:

Callback class

```
class TrackingRecord
  def after_create_commit(record)
    // do thing
  end

  def after_update_commit(record)
    // do thing
  end
end
```

Model

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit TrackingRecord.new
  after_update_commit TrackingRecord.new

  // other stuff
end
```

How can I write after create/update commit callback in class? Or if I have to define `after_commit` how can I tell which is create and which is update?

Thank you!

Comment: You can specify that the callback should only be fired by a certain action with the `:on` option, e.g `after_commit :do_foo, on: :create` and so on ... reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. If there `after_update_commit` is triggered do you expect `TrackingRecord.new.after_create_commit(self)` to run?

Comment: @spickermann no, per document it should map callbacks accordingly, ie when `after_update_commit` is triggered `TrackingRecord.new.after_update_commit` should be run, but it required `after_commit` instead

Comment: In your case I would create a Concern https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html that adds the callbacks and then include the concern where needed

Answer (score 0):

Rails's `after_commit` is called after a record has been created, updated, or destroyed.

For each case, you can use `after_create`, `after_update`, `after_destroy` callback or using `on` option with `after_commit`.

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  # after_create, after_update
  after_create :do_after_create
  after_update :do_after_update

  # OR using on option
  after_commit :do_after_create, on: :create
  after_commit :do_after_update, on: :update

  def do_after_create
     # Using your class
     TrackingRecord.new.after_create_commit(self)
     # or do something here
  end
  
  def do_after_update
     # Using your class
     TrackingRecord.new.after_update_commit(self)
     # or do something here
  end

end
```

Hope it helps :D